# changing variable value in java

Tags: java, android

I try to design an app for android.

I want, when tapping a button1, `x` set to 1, and for button2 `y` set to 1, etc.

Then use these variables in the if statements.

```
int z;
int y;
int w;
final Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button m1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
final Button m2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
m.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // some code here
        z == 1;
        return false;
    }
});
m1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // some code here
        z == 1;
        return false;
    }
});
m2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // some code here
        z == 1;
        return false;
    }
});
if (x == 1 & y == 1 & z == 1) {
    finish();
    //some code here
}
```

But the "if" inner block is never reached; how can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably learn how to format code correctly. Regarding to your problem: Hexafraction is right. You have to use a single equals sign to assign a value to your variable.

Comment: You should use `&&` for logical and, like this `if (x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1)`.  A single `&` is a bitwise operator which will work if everything is an odd number but will not do what you think.

Comment: == is just wrong type 
my problem : "if" not worked (i tried && but not worked yet )

Answer (score 1):

```
z==1;
```

is wrong. `==` is used for comparsions of values<sup>1</sup>, not for setting. Use:

```
z=1;
```

instead. Anyway I'd learn more Java basics before jumping into Android.

---

<sup>1</sup>This will probably come up, so I'd better tell you now rather than later. Strings should never be compared using `==` but with `string1.equals(string2)`.

Comment: == is for wrong type i know its for comparisons i just rush type in in the notepad and paste here 
my problem is "if" not worked !

Comment: @meysam If you are assigning wrong it will cause the ifs to not work as well.